# Alan Wake QR Code

Tags: alan-wake

At the beginning of Act 2 (in New York apartment) on the PC (via Steam) there is a QR code.

[image]

It is located in Alan's Office (if I remember correctly), and it says:

```
Huh. Turns out this isn't too bad even if you're not sitting on a couch
when you play it. Who knew!
```

Is there also a QR code in console versions here?  If so, I would assume the majority of console players would, in fact, be playing on a couch.  Therefore, does it say something else?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that there might be a difference?

Comment: @fbueckert I would assume console players would, in fact, be on a couch most of the time.

Comment: Explanation for downvotes?

Comment: This is actually kind of cool, I probably wouldn't have even noticed the connection.  I suspect you're right, and it's probably a different result in the console version, if it's even there at all.

Comment: There is another QR Code in the game that leads to a website.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusineno yea I saw that one near the beginning of the game

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Alan Wake wiki thi QR codes do not appear in the XBOX 360 version.

**source:** http://alanwake.wikia.com/wiki/QR_Codes